# Typescript Decorator to pass method reference to invoke method somewhere else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, oop, decorator

[Code Here](https://github.com/andrewpump/decoratorsTest)

**High-Level Goal:** I have been tasked to create a ridiculously easy way to expose methods of a class to a `Supervisor` class that can invoke them at any time.  The reason for such a system is so that a developer can go into their codebase and easily choose to expose some functions to this supervisor in a repetitive way.

**Attempted Solution:** Use decorators to pass an object reference to a globally available state in the `Supervisor` class.

**Practical Implementation:** I want to be able to place a decorator like `@exposed` in front of a method in a React class and have the supervisor be able to invoke that method.

**Constraints:**

1. Only a single instance of any given class is created
2. You can only modify the platform with "simple wrappers".  This means you cannot refactor the codebase using a state management system like Redux.  We define a simple wrapper as being a single-line modification for each.  Roughly speaking, we are trying to keep the platform low touch.

Below is my current non-working solution.

**Decorator (@Exposed):** Takes the target and adds

```js
import State from "./state"

export const Exposed = () => {
    return (target: any, propertyKey: string) => {
        State.addFunction(target)
        console.log("DecoratorEqual:", target === State.functions[0]) // true
    }
}
```

**ChildComponent:** A child component within the React application that utilizes `@Exposed`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Exposed } from './decorators';
import State from './state';

export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    @Exposed()
    test(invoker: string) {
        console.log(invoker, this) // Child === invoker ? ChildComponent:undef
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={() => {
                console.log("ChildEqual: ", State.functions[0] === this) // false
                this.test("Child ")}
            }>
            Child Component
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

**App.js:** The Parent component which acts as the `Supervisor` in this case.  Attempts to invoke the reference to the method test.

```js
import './App.css';
import ChildComponent from './ClassComponent';
import State from './state';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <ChildComponent />
                <button onClick={() => 
                { State.functions[0].test.call("Parent ") }}> 
                Click me
                </button>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Questions:**

1. Why when I try to invoke the function from the parent component, does the reference to `this` in `test(invoker: string)` come out `undefined`?  Is there a way to "fix" this?
2. What other alternatives in Typescript/Javascript could emulate this functionality?

Thanks for taking a look at this problem!